# Why am I not getting back the correct values?

Tags: python, debugging

So I'm doing an online Python course and the final assignment is as follows:

"Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below."

```
Invalid input
Maximum is 10
Minimum is 2
```

However it's kicking out 7 for the maximum and 10 for the minimum. I feel like I've looked over every line, but I still don't understand what I'm missing. Thoughts?

My Code is:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
done = False
list = []

# Get user input and test for integer
while done != True:
    user_input = input("Enter a Value: ")
    try:
        int(user_input)
        list.append(user_input)

# Error if not integer -or- break if "Done"
    except:
        if user_input == "done":
            done = True
            break
        print("Invalid input")

# Determine largest and smallest
for num in list:
    if largest is None:
        largest = num
    elif num > largest:
        largest = num
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = num
    elif num < smallest:
        smallest = num

# The end
print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.append(user_input)` appends a string to the list, so all the comparisons are lexicographical.

Also, `list` is a terrible name, don't shadow built-in names

And two style suggestions:

- Avoid using a variable to control the loop. Use `while True` and `break` when appropriate
- It is generally considered a very bad style to catch a general exception type.

```
...
li = []

while True:
    user_input = input("Enter a Value: ")
    try:
        li.append(int(user_input))
    except ValueError:
        if user_input == "done":
            break
        print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you :)
I'll have to be more careful about using predefined words.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `int` converts a string to an int and returns it. Here, you ignore the return value, so in fact, you're comparing the inputs **lexicographically**, not numerically. If you save the return value, you should be OK. e.g.:

```py
user_input = int(user_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

```
list.append(user_input)
```

but what you should do is

```
list.append(int(user_input))
```

because

```
int(user_input)
```

doesn't make user_input into an integer, it returns the integer from user_input
So you can also do:-

```
user_int_input = int(user_input)
list.append(user_int_input)
```

Also don't use the variable name list, list is a predefined keyword by python

Comment: `list` is not a keyword. Keywords can not be overridden. It is "just" a globally available class/type.

Comment: Ah yes sorry by keyword i meant that it is an identifier already used by python